# Using Screen or Tmux with Cyberark PIM Proxy

Tags: proxy

we discover that log of commands typed during a Cyberark PIM Proxy ssh session to a target host are blind if the user open a screen or a tmux session in its shell... Anyone experienced this issue ? is there a workaround ?

Comment: I assume you meant "Cyberark P**S**M *SSH* Proxy"

Comment: The SSH proxy acts by routing all SSH traffic through a jump server which logs activity for audit and SIEM.

Comment: I did some quick searching but didn't find any posts relevant to your issue. I assume you're bit seeing logs for those because they are not directly executing SSH commands, but are seen as commands from an application. If you wrote a BASH script to run commands, does the proxy log those commands?  Maybe it *only* logs direct commands, and not those executed by an executable. If so, that's a pretty glaring loophole in their software.

Comment: This is a question for the vendor and is not a security question